# jQuery Datepicker with multiple options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to get `datepicker` to display the day names I am sending but it still uses default values. Is there something that should be turned off? Should I set values with single option statements? I don't get any errors in Firebug. Here's my code:

```
$('#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-50:+10",
    clickInput: true,
    dayNames: <%= DayNames %> ,
    dayNamesMin: <%= DayNamesMin %> ,
    monthNames: <%= MonthNames %> ,
    montNamesShort: <%=MonthNamesShort %>
});
```

Here's the output:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_body_body_CenterColumn_CvPersonalInfoControl_birthDate_txtDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-50:+10",
            clickInput: true,
            dayNames: ['Pazartesi', 'Salı', 'Çarşamba', 'Perşembe', 'Cuma', 'Cumartesi', 'Pazar'] ,
            dayNamesMin: ['Pzt', 'Sa', 'Çrş', 'Prş', 'Cu', 'Cmt', 'Pzr'] ,
            monthNames: ['Ocak', 'Şubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 'Mayıs', 'Haziran', 'Temmuz', 'Ağustos', 'Eylül', 'Ekim', 'Kasım', 'Aralık'] ,
            monthNamesShort: ['Ock', 'Şbt', 'Mrt', 'Nsn', 'Mys', 'Haz', 'Tem', 'Ağu', 'Eyl', 'Ekm', 'Kas', 'Ara']
        });
});
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of the above code. My guess would be that your `DayNames`, `MonthNames` etc variables are not posting data which can be interpreted as JS arrays when output to the page. Also, it should be `monthNamesShort:`, you're missing an `h`, but I assume thats a typo in your example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan McCrossan I corrected the typo, here's the output.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was a server side thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try doing:

```
$('#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-50:+10",
    clickInput: true,
    dayNames: <%= DayNames %> ,    
    monthNames: <%= MonthNames %> ,
    monthNamesShort: <%=MonthNamesShort %>
});
//the DD - day name long 
check the ref: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate
```

Hope it will be of some help

Comment: I want my current format, names displayed on the calendar are wrong.