# Datepicker, 2nd date is X days from 1st date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've read a lot of different answers to this, but I'm curious as to why my specific way of doing it (which I haven't found online) doesn't not render the desired results.

User selects deliverydate, after which pickupdate datepicker has a maxDate of 14 days from the deliverydate:

```
$( "#deliverydate" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: 1,
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#pickupdate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate, "defaultDate", selectedDate, "maxDate", (Date.parse(selectedDate) - Date.today())/1000/60/60/24 + 14 );
  }
});
```

How I thought to run the calculation was calculate the number of days from today the selectedDate is and then add 14 (since maxDate can take an argument that's an integer representing the number of days from today).

Note I have Date.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after a ton of digging... ugh jQuery Datepicker is not doc'ed well.

Two important factoids:
 1. Datepicker can only be initialized ONCE, thereafter in order to change the settings, you must use `option`
 2. According to Datepicker, you should be able to provide multiple options in a map of option-value pairs, but nothing I do makes this work, and their docs looks just like single option, so ... whatever, I just set 3 options individually.

The way I got it to work is below:

```
$( "#deliverydate" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: 1, // 1 day from today
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: <%= ENV["Days_in_advance"].to_i %>,
  dateFormat: "M d, yy", 

  // despite the docs, it doesnt' look like you can set multiple options at once, so I'm doing it individually 3X below. 
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    deliverydate = Date.parse(selectedDate);
    $( "#pickupdate" ).datepicker("option", 
      { defaultDate: ((deliverydate - Date.today())/1000/60/60/24 + 1 ) });
    // day after deliverydate 
    $( "#pickupdate" ).datepicker("option", 
      { minDate: ((deliverydate - Date.today())/1000/60/60/24 ) });
    // same day as deliverydate
    $( "#pickupdate" ).datepicker("option", 
      { maxDate: ((deliverydate - Date.today())/1000/60/60/24 + <%= ENV["Max_days_of_rental"].to_i %> )});
    // upper limit on rental days
  }
});
$( "#pickupdate" ).datepicker({
  // this is triggered on DOM load and is overwritten the minute a deliverydate is selected per the onClose 
  defaultDate: 1, // 1 day from today
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: <%= ENV["Max_days_of_rental"].to_i %>,
  dateFormat: "M d, yy"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the `datepicker("option", option, value)` syntax for one single option.  Since you are using multiple options for the `$('#pickupdate')` datepicker, you need to specify them as a JSON, as you did for `$(#deliverydate)`.  Like so:

```
$('#pickupdate').datepicker({
    minDate: selectedDate,
    defaultDate: selectedDate,
    maxDate: ((Date.parse(selectedDate) - Date.today())/1000/60/60/24 + 14 )
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielBank/tgpLug6r/) for a working demonstration.

See also [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225111/jquery-datepicker-with-multiple-options) about using jQuery Datepicker with multiple options.

Finally, you should consider changing to [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  The [last release of Date.js was 2007](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/#Overview), so there hasn't been any major or minor releases to it for a long time.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize. Weird... I see that this works in the fiddle (albeit if deliverydate is changed, it looks like pickupdate doesn't change dynamically despite the `onClose` method being called; i.e., I have to refresh the page to see changes). However, on my localhost, nothing works, neither defaultDate nor maxDate, and there are no console errors. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: To have the `datepicker` dynamically change, simply add a call to it's `setDate` function in the `onClose` of the other: `$('#pickupdate').datepicker('setDate', selectedDate);`.  Updated this in the JSFiddle.  Also I added a caveat to my answer that you should consider using Moment.js instead of Date.js.  As for your other issues with nothing working on localhost, it might be best to take that to chat to troubleshoot.  It sounds like the script isn't being loaded if there is nothing in your console (did you try console.log()'ing anything?)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the localhost issue on my end... the script is loaded, so I don't know why it doesn't work. The other question that I had, sorry I didn't clarify, what I meant to say is that in the Fiddle, if you click Nov 14th and then look at pickupdate, it's true that the calendar restricts to no more than 14 days out. BUT if then you click deliverydate to Nov 18th, the pickupdate doesn't update to the new 14 days out. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I figured it out. You're using the onClose to initialize the datepicker, but it turns out datepicker can only be initailized once. Thereafter, settings can ONLIY be changed by the `option` method. See my accepted answer. Thanks for helping!